# Repeater and public array as NOT datasource.

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I want to using two dataSources with repeater. One is binded to dataSource property so my question is is that possible to f.ex. to also repeat some array of string as public property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to bind to a property of your datasource that is also a collection. For example:

```
class Person
{
   List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}

class Phone
{
   string Number { get; set; }
}

 void Page_Load(...)
 {
     List<Person> people = GetPeople();
     peopleRepeater.DataSource = people;
     peaopleRepeater.DataBind();
 }
```

aspx page

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="peopleRepeater" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
        Name : <%# Eval("Name") %>
        Phones: <br/>
       <asp:Repeater ID="phonesRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# (Container.DataItem as Person).Phones %>'>
           <ItemTemplate>
              <%# Eval("Number") %> <br />
           </ItemTemplate>

       </asp:Repeater>

     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most ASP.NET Data controls only will bind to a single data source at a time. It is possible to have nested controls that can be bound to multiple data sources. Some 3rd party controls such as RadGridView are designed to handle multiple datasource binding (e.g. hierachical).